# Is it possible to overlay base graphics on ggmap plots?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, geospatial, ggmap

I'm really resistant to ggplot.  I don't think that it looks nicer than base graphics, it can't be a complete replacement given that various statistical functions have default methods that call base graphics, and it is yet another unnecessary syntax that takes time to learn. Also, stringing together statements with pluses?!?!  /rant

I do however appreciate the functionality in `ggmap`.  I want to overlay base graphics on maps that I download from ggmap, ideally without hacks like first downloading and saving maps images, then loading and using as background.

Is it possible to use base graphics with `ggmap`?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
map<-get_map(location="sanfrancisco",zoom=12, color = 'bw')
plot(map)
X <- c(-122.3957, -122.4240, -122.4129, -122.4034, -122.3965, -122.4082)
Y <- c(37.78892, 37.76317, 37.78535, 37.78764, 37.77833, 37.78736)
locs <- data.frame(X,Y)
with(locs, points(X, Y))
```

No joy. Perhaps if I convert it to a spatialPoints data frame?

```
library(sp)
coordinates(locs)<- ~X+Y
points(locs)
```

Still no joy

Comment: It's likely possible, but would involve digging much further into the internals of `ggplot2` than you'd have to go to just learn it. In this case, you can plot it with just `ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(X, Y), data = locs)`. Mixing base and ggplot (through `grid`, likely) will take a LOT more code than that.

Comment: As a note, I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss `ggplot` as just another unnecessary syntax. It is based on the grammar of graphics - a very well thought and researched foundation for visualization

Comment: Should be doable with the [`gridBase` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/index.html) - see the vignette, it's quite nice.

Comment: You could also just give in and use `ggplot`: `ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = locs, aes(x = X, y = Y))`.

Comment: Or you could work out some coordinate transforms. When you plot the map with `plot(map)`, you are using base plots to display the image - it just doesn't know about latitude and longitude. The coordinates of your base map plot are the pixels, starting with `(0, 0)` in the lower left corner. You can do `points(seq(1, (dim(map)[1]), length = 10), seq(1, (dim(map)[2]), length = 10))`. You can access the "bounding box" of the map in lat/long with `attr(map, "bb")`.

Comment: Rewrite `ggmap` to use base graphics if you dislike the `ggplot2` idiom so much. /rantback